NextJS multi language next-intl hydration errors (SOLVED)
I am using NextJS 14. When I installed everything for multi language from next-intl and I check from offical website but system is giving couple hydration errors!

created i18n.ts
updated next.config.mjs
created middleware.ts
created [locale] folder and created layout.tsx and page.tsx inside the [locale] folder

all codes are below:
i18n.ts
import {notFound} from 'next/navigation';
import {getRequestConfig} from 'next-intl/server';

// Can be imported from a shared config
const locales = ['en', 'nl', 'de', 'tr'];

export default getRequestConfig(async ({locale}) => {
    // Validate that the incoming `locale` parameter is valid
    if (!locales.includes(locale as any)) notFound();

    return {
        messages: (await import(`./languages/${locale}.json`)).default
    };
});

next.config.mjs
import createNextIntlPlugin from 'next-intl/plugin';

const withNextIntl = createNextIntlPlugin();

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    images: {
        domains: [
            "avatars.githubusercontent.com",
            "lh3.googleusercontent.com",
            "res.cloudinary.com",
            "images.unsplash.com"
        ]
    }
};

export default withNextIntl(nextConfig);


middleware.ts
import createMiddleware from 'next-intl/middleware';

export default createMiddleware({
    // A list of all locales that are supported
    locales: ['en', 'nl', 'de', 'tr'],

    // Used when no locale matches
    defaultLocale: 'en'
});

export const config = {
    // Match only internationalized pathnames
    matcher: ['/', '/(en|nl|de|tr)/:path*']
};


layout.tsx
import {NextIntlClientProvider} from 'next-intl';
import {getMessages} from 'next-intl/server';

export default async function LocaleLayout({children, params: {locale}}: {
    children: React.ReactNode;
    params: {locale: string};
}) {
    // Providing all messages to the client
    // side is the easiest way to get started
    const messages = await getMessages();

    return (
        <html lang={locale}>
        <body>
        <NextIntlClientProvider messages={messages}>
            {children}
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
        </body>
        </html>
    );
}


page.tsx
import {useTranslations} from 'next-intl';

export default function Index() {
    const t = useTranslations('home_page');
    return (
        <h1>{t('slider_title')}</h1>
    );
}



I checked a lot of different website and questions and answers but I couldn't find any correct answer. But I don't now what I need to do?

Can you update next to 14.2 to see better hydration diff and replace the last screen shot

Upgrade to latest version, but still continue :(
"next": "^14.2.3",
    "next-intl": "^3.13.0",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",

https://imgur.com/a/KqRAtRx

Please, share a Minimal, Reproducible repository

Hi Ahmed,
thank you first of all. I fixed the problem. Solution was, upgrade nextjs to lastest version but didn't change anything. Delete the project and install nextjs latest version, after that install next-intl and check the all installation steps. Now working.

I had the same problem, I had created the [locale] folder and moved everything inside. I thought the problem was in the use of the middleware or with next-i18n-router, the problem was so simple that it took me 4 hours to find it, I had left loading.js outside of [locale]. It seems that everything outside of [locale] causes problems when using the middleware
